# How to stop or remove videostream from Flash Builder View

Tags: flash, view, builder, video-player

I'm having problems getting the video stream generated by this view to stop once the user either attempts to click the back button or changes view.  Can someone help us figure how to add a stop to the exiting back button so that when clicked the stream stops and then navigates properly?

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
viewDeactivate="view1_viewDeactivateHandler(event)"    
initialize="view1_initializeHandler(event)" 
backgroundColor="#000000" title="{data.title}">

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.core.mx_internal;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
protected function liveStream_completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(!this.parentApplication.isTablet) 
theGroup.horizontalScrollPosition = liveStream.width / 2;

bi.visible = false;
}

protected function view1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, deviceKeyDownHandler);
systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, deviceKeyUpHandler);
}

protected function deviceKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK && navigator.length > 1){
event.preventDefault(); 
this.liveStream.source = null;
this.liveStream.source = VideoPlayer;
}
}

protected function deviceKeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK && navigator.length > 1){
 navigator.popView(); 
}
}

protected function view1_viewDeactivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
systemManager.stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, deviceKeyDownHandler);
systemManager.stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, deviceKeyUpHandler);
}

]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:navigationContent>
<s:Button label="Back" visible="{!this.parentApplication.isTablet}" 
click="navigator.popView()"/>
</s:navigationContent>


<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%" id="streamScroller">
<s:Group id="theGroup">
<s:VideoPlayer width="100%" height="100%" complete="liveStream_completeHandler(event)"
source="some_source/livestream.f4m" maintainProjectionCenter="true" scaleMode="zoom" id="liveStream"/>
</s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
<s:BusyIndicator id="bi" width="40" height="40"  horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>

</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously you need to move existing button click behavior to new handler, like this:

```
<s:Button ... click="buttonHandler()"/>
```

and then add a handler

```
protected function buttonHandler():void
{
   this.liveStream.source = null // stop stream
   navigator.popView() // moved behavior
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Roman!!  That worked like a charm and saved an Amateur coder like myself!!